# Why does jQueryUI menu return wrong item immediately after enabled?

Tags: jquery-ui

Sample code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/mrtidy/w3zx0n4o/

Here's the key bits:

```
<ul id="testmenu">
    <li data-menu-id="edit"><a href="#">edit</a></li>
    <li class="ui-state-disabled" data-menu-id="delete"><a href="#">delete</a></li>
</ul>
```

... and then the JS ...

```
$("#testmenu").menu();
$("#testmenu").on("menuselect", function(event, ui) {
    $("#feedback").text("selected " + ui.item.data("menuId"));
});

// some event causes an element to be enabled
$('[data-menu-id="delete"]').removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
```

I've verified the behaviour in FF and Chrome.

If you click delete immediately after it is enabled then you see "selected edit" but I would expect to see "selected delete".  Why does this happen and is there anything that I can do to improve this?

UPDATE: I've found more details about this.  Here's a more specific repro.

1. open the jsfiddle link
2. put the mouse over the top of the edit menu option
3. use keyboard to refresh page (e.g. F5 or Ctrl-r)
4. once the page draws you should see the edit get 'active' style
5. move the mouse to point to delete (before it gets enabled)
6. once delete gets enabled you can click delete and see 'selected edit'

You don't need to rush on step 6 anymore - as long as you don't move the mouse too much then edit remains the active item and when you click on delete it'll think you chose edit.

Comment: _If you click delete immediately after it is enabled then you see "selected edit" but I would expect to see "selected delete"._ I see selected delete, not selected edit.

Comment: This appears to be the core of the problem I'm seeing:

`this.active = this.active || $( event.target ).closest( ".ui-menu-item" );`

That is the first line of the select function in the jQuery-UI Menu plugin.  The event.target is correct but since this.active is set that is what is used.  It happens to be the wrong value (is set to the first active item in the menu).

Comment: I'm currently working-around this issue in my code by watching mouseenter / mouseout from the time that I show my menu until the time that optional items get enabled; if an optional item does become enabled late (like in the repro case) then I inform the Menu widget by triggering a mouseenter event after the element gets enabled.  I'd love suggestions on alternatives.